# Hide nav class - woocommerce theme

Tags: html, css, woocommerce

I'd like to remove nav class from product page:
I mean "Strona główna główna/ Desportivo" above the title of product.
http://sklepdesportivo.pl/produkt/czapka-money-magnet/

Can I hide it in CSS? How?

Comment: you want to hide nav or just remove css class?

Comment: You mean that you want to remove the text or modify it?

Comment: I mean hide this nav above the title :)

Comment: Do you just want to delete it?

Comment: css is display:none;

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please review the guidelines for asking questions, especially [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

```
.woocommerce-breadcrumb{
display:none !important;
}
```

Add this into active child theme's style.css

Comment: @user313215 if not -> try in class .product-info .breadcrumbs{

Answer (score 0):

When using a good template, breadcrumbs can be set/unset through the admin panel. To switch it off on the product detail page, add the following CSS:

```
.single-product nav.woocommerce-breadcrumb.breadcrumbs {
  display: none;
}
```

Comment: When I add it manually in Chrome Development Tool, it works fine. Are you sure you put it in the right .css file? Have you tried clearing the cache?